# Working with Shopify Variants dropdown select

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

in my product template page i have this code:

```
<select name="id" id="ProductSelect-{{ section.id }}" class="product-single__variants">
```

I'm using a javascript snippet to hide variants based on the customers choices. I want to use one snippet file for all my products, but cannot get javascript to read the following:

```
var productSelect = "ProductSelect-{{ section.id }}";
```

how would i do this? My alternative is that i have a snippet file for each product which although possible, makes it long and arduous.
Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use `document.querySelector("select[id^=ProductSelect]").value` to grab the value. Unless you have multiple `<select>`s?

Comment: unfortunately there are two selects on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you're running into is that `{{ section.id }}` is a template variable. In the rendered HTML, that part is replaced by the appropriate variable.  Once your javascript runs, there will be no element on the page with double-curly-braces in any of its attributes.

There are a few ways that you might be able to get around this:

### Idea 1: Store the section ID somewhere

To do this, you would need to have some place where you can associate section IDs with sections that have loaded on the page, tying that piece of data to something that your snippet already knows about when it runs.

If, say, your snippet knows the product handle of whatever product is being changed, you could add something like this inside the form:

```
<script>
  // If our lookup object already exists, do nothing. Otherwise, initialize it as an empty object
  window.section_lookup = window.section_lookup || {};

  //Now save the section ID using the product's handle
  //Using the json filter when we print Liquid variables to Javascript ensures that the resulting value is always Javascript-legal.
  section_lookup[{{ product.handle | json}}] = {{ section.id | json }};
</script>
```

Now, in your lookup code, you can use:

```
// Assuming that you have a variable called product_handle already
var productSelect = "ProductSelect-" + section_lookup[product_handle];
```

Which will give you the specific ID that you're looking for.

### Idea 2: Use the power of the `form` object

Is your code snippet running in some context where you know something about any of the elements that contain the select element you want?  For example, do you already know the form or the product-area wrapper?

If you have the `form` that contains your select box, you're golden.  Every form knows the names of all of the form-fields contained inside it.  Since the field's name is `id`, getting to the right select box from the form object is as easy as:

```
// Assuming you have a variable named form representing the correct form, access the form field with the name 'id'
var idField = form['id'];
```

**NOTE:** If your form is jQuery-selected, you probably *won't* have that ability.  Fortunately, if you're stuck with a jQuery-wrapped object you can easily un-wrap it like so:

```
// Assuming somebody gave you a variable named $form that they jQuery-selected....
var form = $form[0];
var idField = form['id'];
```

If you don't have the form but you do have quick access to any other input inside the form, you're also in luck - Every form element (ie: inputs, selects, textareas, fieldsets...) also knows what form it belongs to.

```
// Assuming that there is a variable named target which is a form element contained in the same form as the ID field that we want:
var form = target.form;
var idField = form['id'];
```

### Idea 3: Use some other wrapping element to constrain your lookup

If you know anything about some wrapping element that contains the select box that you want and doesn't include the select box that you don't want, you can constrain your query-selector to only look inside the wrapper. That way, you'll only find the element that you need.

If you're using plain ol' "vanilla" Javascript:

```
//Assuming we have a variable named product_wrapper
var idField = product_wrapper.querySelector('[name="id"]');
```

Or if you prefer jQuery:

```
//Still assuming that we have a variable named product_wrapper
var idField = jQuery('[name="id"]', product_wrapper);
```

---

Hopefully you can find success with at least one of these methods. Good luck!